# Edit page error how to fix?

Tags: php, mysql

I seem to have problem fixing this:

```
<?php

$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "learningnews";
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', $username, $password, $database);
$id = $_GET["title"];

$show = "SELECT * FROM learningnews.news where title = '$id'";
$ending = mysql_query($show);
$now = mysql_fetch_array($ending);

?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Edit Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table border="1">
      <form method="post" action="newsedit.php">
    <tr>
      <td>    
      <input type="text" name="name" size="40" value="<?php echo "$now[title]" ?>"> 
    </tr>
      </td>
    <tr>
      <td>  
      <input type="text" name="name1" size="500" value="<?php echo "$now[content]" ?>">
    </tr>
      </td>
      </form> 
  </tr>
    </td>
      </table>      
</body>
</html>
```

I seem can't get to show of the title and the content that I have in my database so that I can edit it I get this error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: title in C:\xampp\htdocs\newsedit.php on line 6
```

Could someone help please ?

EDIT : Heres the code where I submit the news and ouput them.

EDIT2 : Re-posted the second php file. Here how it looks. This time, no error but it doesnt show the content and title i want .. in the input fields.

```
<?php

$id ="";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "learningnews";
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', $username, $password, $database);

$show = "SELECT * FROM learningnews.news where title = '$id'";
$ending = mysql_query($show);
$now = mysql_fetch_array($ending);

?>

<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table border="1">
      <form method="post" action="newsedit.php">
    <tr>
      <td>    
      <input type="text" name="title" size="40" value="<?php echo "$now[title]" ?>"> 
    </tr>
      </td>
    <tr>
      <td>  
      <input type="text" name="content" size="500" value="<?php echo "$now[content]" ?>">
    </tr>
      </td>
      </form> 
  </tr>
    </td>
      </table>      
</body>
</html>
```

Basically, I need the ouput from first code to show in second and so I can edit it then update it.

Comment: Your `$_GET['title']` is not defined, do you have a `<input>` with `name="title"` in your `<form>`?

Comment: No but when i put title in one of them i get 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$show' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\newsedit.php on line 10

Comment: `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used in new applications and will be removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices.

Comment: still that doesnt .. really help me

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the variable is set with [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) before you use it.

```
<?php
   if(isset($_GET['title']))
      $id = $_GET["title"];
?>
```

In your previous page's code you need to change the form method to GET so you can check your title with $_GET on the next page.

```
<form method="GET" action="admin.php">
    <input type="text" name="title">
    <textarea name="content"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="posthorses"/>
</form>
```

Comment: I get this Notice: Undefined variable: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\newsedit.php on line 13

Line 13  $show = "SELECT * FROM learningnews.news where title = '$id'";

Comment: You have to set a default value if not set.  
   if(isset($_GET['title']))
      $id = $_GET["title"];
   else
      $id = 1;

Comment: Ok this time i dont get error but .. it doesnt show my news so i can edit themm .. its just black input fields

Comment: Looking at your new edits I see your problem.  The code where you submit the news and output them has a form.  You need to do <form method="GET" action="admin.php">

Comment: I don't really get how to get this done, im not doing something right.

Comment: still doesn't work ;/
I made it withouth GET but still not showing me .. the content from my first page

Comment: but this time atleast ... the url is better it says
http://127.0.0.1/newsedit.php?id=neznam I will post the changed one

Comment: You need the url to say title not id.  You can always debug your query by echoing $show and using that result to see if your database is in line.

Comment: Try going to this url:  127.0.0.1/newsedit.php?title=neznam  You are using $_GET['title'] so you need to set a variable in your form with the name="title"

Comment: Both ways nothing happen .. even with GET nothing shows

Comment: When i go to the URL .. http://127.0.0.1/newsedit.php?title=neznam it shows the title and content i want :O why ... doesnt workk

Comment: when i dlete the where title = id part it it shows me only the first 
news.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

if ( isset( $_GET['name'] ) )
{
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $database = "learningnews";
    $db = mysql_connect('localhost', $username, $password, $database);
    $id = $_GET["name"];

    $show = "SELECT * FROM learningnews.news where title = '$id'";
    $ending = mysql_query($show);
    $now = mysql_fetch_array($ending);
}

?>
```

Because `$_GET["title"];` was never defined. Not sure what are you trying to do with `title`.

Comment: I was trying to get it from the database - table .. so i can edit it :) and update it on the news output page :) When i put it like it, it shows me taht $now is undefined .. in the form

Comment: @user3429407 and from where does you except `$_GET['title']` to come from there isn't any field in the form

Comment: in my table ... its named title

Comment: I will just post the first file .. where i submit and ouput them

Comment: try this: go to your page.php?title=your_title. with your previous code

Comment: like im not at the updating stage yet ... because it doesnt let me output and edit them first in the second page